# Alternative python package repositories

Tags: python, firewall, package-managers

my work network is a little paranoid and has blocked, among other things, access to python.org. Are there any reputable alternate python package repositories that I can point pip to?

P.S. They also block github and sourceforge, but do allow bitbucket, enthought, and activepython. Go figure.

P.P.S. It's a military hospital. But I'm trying to do some informatics research and it's killing me. crate.io is also blocked. The remaining two are in China, so I'm pretty sure that won't go over well. Can I mirror PyPi myself?

Comment: When you say "package repositories", are you referring to the Python installer and/or source packages, or to PyPI?

Comment: Go to the network admin and slap him/her silly.  As a developer, access to third-party libraries and packages is extremely important because you don't want to be re-inventing the wheel (especially if you know that a certain package exists and is what you want).

Comment: Also, if they're blocking by domain, you may want to try just using a third-party DNS server (there are plenty of them with web-based front ends) to look up `pypi.python.org` and then using the IP address.

Comment: Meanwhile… does your company have a policy against allowing software development, or do they just bill for your time and want to do anything they can to inflate it? Otherwise, blacklisting sites like `python.org` or `pypi.python.org` isn't "a little paranoid", it's "insanely stupid".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

Choose a mirror from [this list](https://www.pypi-mirrors.org/) and add it to the file in this path: `~/.pip/pip.conf`. For instance, I switch the default mirror to the one in Tsinghua University: 

`[global]
index-url = https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple`

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for PyPI mirrors, there's an up-to-date list at http://www.pypi-mirrors.org.

The primary mirrors are under python.org, but there are some under other domains. As of 7 Aug 2013 (in case you can't reach the mirrors site either) they are:

- pypi.crate.io
- pypi.douban.com
- pypi.hustunique.com

---

From your edit, you ask:

> Can I mirror PyPI myself?

Yes, you can. As [the main mirrors page](https://pypi.python.org/mirrors) says:

> Use the [bandersnatch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bandersnatch) mirroring client to set up your own mirror.

Comment: simple.crate.io appears to also be unavailable, and the other two are Chinese. I work at a US military hospital, trying to do some research. I ended up using my phone to ssh to a vps to run dig, which still didn't work.

Comment: @Niels: Can you talk to your admin? Seriously, if they're preventing you from reaching PyPI, there are only two possibilities: (1) They don't realize what they're doing, and you can get it changed, or (2) They know exactly what they're doing, and you will probably get in trouble for trying to work around it.

Comment: yeah, I think I'm going to have to chat with someone. The admins will undoubtedly say no, then I will have to go find a department head and try to explain.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an alternative package repository for Python, Rust, and other languages I would recommend https://cloudsmith.io/ as it offers public, private, and open source repositories. Depending on your needs you can also select a plan with a white-labelled domain but the open-source repository would likely be a great starting point.

Full disclosure, I work there and think it's awesome!

Comment: There are also self-hosting repository mirror products such as Nexus https://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus-repository which in high-security environments are sometimes viewed more favourably than cloud options.